# Price Range in Drupal

Tags: 6, views

I am using ubercart where I enter different price ranges.

In the left sidebar, I want to display different price ranges like:

```
less than 20$
21-40$
41-65$
more than 65$
```

So that whenever I click on one of these items all products in that price range will show up.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use facetapi or faceted_search‎ module i think it helpful..

Answer (score 0):

You could go with the [Search API Range](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_ranges) module form where you can filter product by the price range ..